# External Content Types - Valid Filter Parameters in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016

I have an external database from which I need to get a list of records and as a parameter I must send the user's "Email" in SharePoint 2016 session. I am using to connect the external SharePoint Designer database through "External Content Type ". The problem is that I can not find a way to send the "email" parameter of the logged-in user to return only the records associated with the user. There is a "Filter Parameters Configuration" option in SharePoint Designer but I do not know how to indicate the email filter of the user in session.

[image]

Maybe I need to do it another way? How could jquery.SPServices help me? I want to avoid going to Visual Studio to develop this functionality. I have SharePoint 2016 installed.

Thank you very much for your help.